# How to set the value of a form item based on selected value?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 2 relevant form fields, country code and country (here the field "Land" is suppossed to be the country code.)
[image]

Now I want the value of country code to populate when I select a country and vice versa, that country is selected when I enter a country code. The value from the option for the country is the country code.

I tried something like the following which correctly populates the country code based on the selected field but I don't now how to make it the other way round, how to set the selected element in the option for a country code that was entered.

```
 <div class="fl20">Land:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="2" id="landkod1" "value="<%if (ansokanInfo.getUppfinnareList().contains(editPerson) || ansokanInfo.getSokandeList().contains(editPerson)  ){out.write(editPerson.getLandKod());} %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LANDKOD %>">&nbsp;


        <select name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LAND %>" onchange=document.getElementById('landkod1').value=this.value>
<% 
for(Land land: pc.getLander()) {
%>
<option value="<%=land.getLandKod()%>"><%=land.getLandNamn()%></option>
<% 
}
%>

        </select>
```

Can you tell how it should be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this as javascript and html, I'm going to assume you want a solution based on it. I'm also going to assume you can use jquery, because frankly, its a lot easier for me.

```
$('#landkod1').change(function(){
    //assuming your land combo has an id - "landSelect"
    var selectElement = $('#landSelect'),
        me = $(this), val = me.val().trim();
    selectElement.find('option').each(function(i, item){
        var self = $(item), selfVal = self.val();
        if(selfVal === val){
            selectElement.val(selfVal);
            return false;//break out of the each loop
        }
    });
});
```

[Check the example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwLkN/1/)